# What is happening to the width of these divs in IE 11, and how can I fix it?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-table, width

If you look at http://jsbin.com/tacabepaju/1/edit?html,css,output in IE 11 you will see that the red box is extremely wide, and its parent is even wider (in turn causing its parent to be super wide). Chrome and Firefox render these divs as expected.

What is causing the red .table div to be so wide in IE, and why is its parent even wider? How can I fix this?

The code in the jsbin is a stripped down version of what I'm dealing with in production.

```
.column {
  position: relative;
  width: 83.33333%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.picker {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.table {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got what I *assume* is your desired result using the following:

```
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.picker {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.table {
  /* position: relative; */
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-color: red;
}
```

I noticed that the problem started with the `.card` element which did not have an CSS included and was the first element to expand outside the bounds of its parent, with the child element of `.picker` and `.table` following suit.

I'm not sure how flexible you are on `display: table` - if this is essential or not so you could change this to `display: flex` but I think you need to use flex all the way down for it to behave nicely.

*Disclaimer: I haven't used flexbox a whole lot myself.*

Answer (score 0):

You should either set `.card` to `display:flex` too, or set it to `flex: 1 1 100%;` if for whatever reason you want `.picker` to be a flex-container but not a flex-item.

Answer (score -2):

You can fix this by setting the **box-sizing** CSS attribute to **border-box**

```css
body * {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You can check this doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing for more info on box-sizing.

Comment: that fixes the slight overflow on the last element, but doesn't make a thing for the much bigger IE bug the OP was asking about